# Save uploaded files to Google Drive from website built on Ruby Volt

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, voltrb

I'm building a web site using Ruby Volt for a publication. I'd like users to be able to upload images that will be stored on Google Drive. The Google Drive will belong to the publication, not to the site users who are uploading the images. If possible, I'd like the fact the images are being stored on Google Drive to be transparent to the site users.

The publication staff will access the images via their Google Drive.

My head is swimming with the Google documentation… Does anybody know if this is doable? If it is can you offer any pointers to example code or suggestions on how to get started?

Comment: this is well covered in other s.om questions for the general usage of drive api. read about how to use oauth2 in drive. worst case if you dont find a library for your language, use the http rest api.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic

Answer (score 0):

So I can't help with the google drive API side of things, but in Volt, you can use a HttpController to post a input type="field".  In the http controller, you can call params._field_name to get the data from rest.  That will provide a tempfile you can copy out.  Once I get time I'll make a demo app for file upload.

Comment: this is not what he is asking about.